# ReactJS - How to get authenticated users data from Node js API?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

so I have tested my API route `/getUser` using Postman which is receiving data successfully being received in json format. However the Jwt token which is stored in localstorage and past in the headers is not being verified as within my browser I receive 'Access denied. No JWT provided' which is sent with a 401 status.

Nodejs API is below this includes my authentication route and `/getUser`which users a middleware file found below also which verifies the token

```
const express = require('express');
const users = express.Router();
const cors = require('cors');
const moment = require('moment');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
// var exjwt = require('express-jwt');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const User = require('../models/User');

const config = require('config');

// const secret = 'dassdfdd';

users.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);

users.use(bodyParser.json());

users.use(cors());

users.post('/authenticate', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
        const payload = {
          id: user.id,
          name: user.first_name
        };
        var token = jwt.sign(payload, config.get('secret'), {
          expiresIn: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
        });

        // res.cookie('auth', token);
        res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
        // return the information including token as JSON
        // // res.setHeader('token', token);
        // res.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        res.send({
          message: 'authentication done ',
          token: token,
          user: user.toJSON()
        });

        console.log(token);
        console.log('Successful Login');
        console.log(user.first_name);
      } else {
        res.json({ message: 'please check your password !' });
        console.log('incorrect password');
      }
    } else {
      res.json({ message: 'user not found !' });
      console.log('user cannot be found');
    }
  });
});

users.get('/protected', (req, res) => {
  res.send('protected');
});


users.get('/getUser', auth, function(req, res) {
  // const currentUser = req.;
  // const id = parseInt(req.params.id);

  const users = User.findOne({
    where: { id: req.user.id }
  });
  //   }
  // });
  // if (!users) {
  //   return res.status(404).send('Cannot find your team players');
  // }
  console;
  res.status(200).json(users);
});


module.exports = users;
```

Login Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

    class Login extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          email: '',
          password: '',
          errors: {}
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
      }

      onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      }
      onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // const user = {
        //   email: this.state.email,
        //   password: this.state.password
        // };

        axios
          .post('http://localhost:5000/api/authenticate', {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
          })
          .then(res => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
            this.props.history.push('/Profile');
          });
      }
```

auth.js this is my middleware file

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header('Authorization');

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).send('Access denied. No JWT provided.');
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('secret'));
    res.set('Authorization', token);
    req.user = decoded;

    next();
  } catch (ex) {
    res.status(400).send('Invalid JWT.');
  }
};
```

Profile Component( this is the page , i want the users data to appear)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getJwt } from '../helpers/jwt';
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // users: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const jwt = getJwt();
    if (!jwt) {
      this.props.history.push('/Login');
    }


axios
  .get('http://localhost:5000/api/getUser', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}` }
  })
  .then(res => {
    this.profile = res.data;
    console.log('profile is:', res.data);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

}

Comment: You can use Network tab in chrome's dev tool to view your request. Check if it has header value

Comment: @TienDuong I can see the token within the request headers , it is stored in the Authorization field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `auth.js` middleware file, you have  `const token = req.header('Authorization');`. This includes the Bearer prefix which is not part of the JWT itself, and will need to be removed before the token can be parsed by the JWT library.

The Bearer prefix identifies the token type as a [Bearer token under the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750). If you wish to support other token types the prefix will be different to identify the respective type and framework.

Comment: When I removed const token , I now receive token is not defined which is correct however I am unclear what i am meant to define token as. I gave that website a read which you linked. hopefully you can help me furhter. thanks for the reply

Comment: Cheers  got it working ,   let token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers['authorization']; // Express headers are auto converted to lowercase
  if (token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    // Remove Bearer from string
    token = token.slice(7, token.length);
  }

  const options = {
    expiresIn: '2d'

  };

Comment: just for future reference to those with same problem

Comment: Glad to help. Your original method `req.header('Authorization')` actually works as too since the req.header() method, which is an alias for req.get(), is case-insensitive, see https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get. for Express 4.x. Important part was to remove the "Bearer" portion from the front part of the string value which was returned from the method.